# Cookie Banner is not shown [403 error]

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy, json

I need help with the following scenario:

1. In a website, `OneTrust cookies` are implemented. The cookies are from an external company.
2. The cookie solution is implemented by including a couple of references to the `OneTrust CDN`, which loads `JavaScript` to the page, that shows the cookies.
3. The Header data is as expected.

I have `automation tests` using `Selenium` and `C#` to check for the presence of `cookie banner` and `accept cookies`.

When I run the automation, the page does not display the cookie banner. Where as, banner shows during manual testing.

The `Chrome Dev tools` showed `403 error`  and found, that a `JSON response` in one of the cookie related `JavaScript file` is not getting loaded and is within the `OnTrust code`. This is happening always and the automation tests are failing in `Azure pipeline`.

But sometimes these tests are passing in my local machine.

Is there any way to overcome this?
Is there a possibility to add the `JSON content` during the automation run, like, when I open the URL and I add the `JSON content`?

Comment: have you tried changing the user agent ? or ading a wait for cookie banner to be displayed

Comment: Thank you @PDHide for the response. Wait is added but is not helpful. Changing the user-agent is not possible due to a Chrome-extension that is used for an authorisation and is not supported by other browsers.